# fnameescape() : add other characters to be escaped (parenthesis, commas etc)

Tags: filetype-tex, escape

I looked around for a long time but did not find any solution for that. On my Unix system (Ubuntu), using LaTeX-suite, I need to escape some characters in file names for compilation, say parenthesis (,) and comma ,.

I modified a bit my compilation script following 
[LaTex-vim cannot compile files with spaces in name](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/latex-vim-cannot-compile-files-with-spaces-in-name)
and now spaces are indeed escaped. The problem is that fnameescape() does not escape commas or parenthesis.

Is there any way I could add ( ) and , as new characters to be escaped by that function ?

If not, is there any way I can change my line

> let mainfname = fnameescape(Tex_GetMainFileName(':p:t'))

in compiler.vim to also escape commas and parenthesis ?

Thanks a lot !

---

**EDIT** : Here is a temporary solution I found, seems to work but since I'm not an expert it might lead to further problems at some point. For the moment, it worked with the following filename

> DM8 - Devoir libre (fonctions, probas).tex

In ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim at line 112 I added the two times three subsitute() lines by hand :

```
if exists('b:fragmentFile')
    let mainfname = fnameescape(expand('%:p:t'))

    let mainfname = substitute(mainfname,'(', '\\(','g')
    let mainfname = substitute(mainfname,')', '\\)','g')
    let mainfname = substitute(mainfname,',', '\\,','g')

    call Tex_CD(expand('%:p:h'))
else
    let mainfname = fnameescape(Tex_GetMainFileName(':p:t'))

    let mainfname = substitute(mainfname,'(', '\\(','g')
    let mainfname = substitute(mainfname,')', '\\)','g')
    let mainfname = substitute(mainfname,',', '\\,','g')
```

Comment: have a look at the `escape()` function, to escape custom characters.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [`:h escape()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#escape%28%29)

```
escape({string}, {chars})               *escape()*
        Escape the characters in {chars} that occur in {string} with a
        backslash.
```

So your line could be something like this (and you can remove the `substitute` calls)

```
let mainfname = escape(fnameescape(expand('%:p:t')), '(),')
```

Note that I still use `fnameescape()` because according to [`:h fnameescape()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#fnameescape%28%29) the characters escaped by function are system specific and you probably don't want to maintain that by yourself.